# Bluemix connect and compose - Failed to fetch list of bluemix services

Tags: ibm-cloud, connect-compose

I'm trying to use new Connect & Compose service on Bluemix. Compose seems to work all right, but when I choose DB in "Connect", and then tried to proceed vi "Next" button. But I got "Failed to fetch list of bluemix services" error message. See the screenshot below.

[Failed to fetch list of bluemix services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST0bo.png)

Is there any prerequisite setting  or some issues with my space ? (I suspect the later, since I have multiple services in my spaces).

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

I've just tried to use the *Connect & Compose* service on Bluemix and I managed to connect to a SQL Database instance previously bound to an application. I have many services in my space, too. Probably you're right, there is a problem with your space, I suggest you to open a ticket to Bluemix Technical Support. Please note that this is a new BETA service. Refer to [Bluemix - Getting customer support](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/troubleshoot/getting_customer_support.html#bluemix_support) for further information.